# Conexão anulando ao rodar script socket php

Tags: php, socket, conexão, host

Estou montando um servidor socket em php, um simples chat. Quando mando alguma mensagem ou fecho uma página, aparece o seguinte erro: "**Warning: socket_recv() Unable to read from socket[10053] : Uma conexão estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador host**" e na outra linha a mesma mensagem, só que com socket_write(), isso só acontece quando coloco socket_write para enviar as mensagens para todos os clientes, veja um trecho do código:

```
foreach($read as $read_socket){
$bytes = socket_recv($read_socket, $data, 1024, null);
if($bytes === 0){
    $key = array_search($read_socket, $array_clients);
    unset($array_clients[$key]);
    echo PHP_EOL . "Cliente desconectado...";
}else{
    foreach($array_clients as $clients)
        socket_write($clients, $data, strlen($data));
}
```

}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso é muito estranho pois já desativei o firewall e o avast e o erro continua. Sempre que um cliente se desconecta e socket_write() não esta presente, aparece normalmente a mensagem "Cliente desconectado..." só que caso eu de um echo $data dentro do else para mostrar as mensagens de outros clientes, aparece "♥Ú" e depois a mensagem dizendo que o cliente foi desconectado. Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Fiz uma alteração no código e rodou, logicamente que ficou uma gambiarra e que pode dar problema a qualquer momento pois percebi que o simbolo estranho "♥Ú" retorna 8 bytes pela função socket_recv, então tive que colocar um if para evitar o envio dele, mas como eu disse, isso ficou uma gambiarra pois mensagens curtas com menos de 3 caracters não são enviadas.

```
foreach($read as $changed_socket){
            $bytes = socket_recv($changed_socket, $data, 2048, null);

            if($bytes === 0){
                unset($array_clients[array_search($changed_socket, $array_clients)]);
                echo "Cliente $changed_socket desconectado.";
            }elseif($bytes === false){
                $this->sock_error();
            }else{
                if($bytes>8){
                    $msg = "MSG($changed_socket):" . $this->unmask($data) . "<br />";
                    $msg = $this->mask($msg);
                    foreach($array_clients as $conectados)
                        socket_write($conectados, $msg, strlen($msg));
                }
            }

        }
```

É o seguinte, quando o cliente se desconecta, primeiro o socket_recv recebe uma mensagem (Isso não deveria acontecer) que no caso é esses simbolos estranhos "♥Ú", no próximo loop é que ele realmente desconecta o cliente e exibe a mensagem "Cliente desconectado...". Isso está muito estranho, pois o certo seria, assim que o socket_select percebe uma alteração no $read, ele deveria imediatamente passar o socket que quer fechar a conexão, entretanto ele só faz isso no próximo loop, como posso resolver esse problema? Será que pode ser lixo de memória?